# Text Analysis webpage does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, html, object

For a homework assignment, I have to make a web page that has a text area. The user inputs some text, hits the analyse button, and the output is supposed to be a list of the frequency of words of a given number of characters. For example, "one two three" would be two words of three characters and one word of five characters. The text area works fine, but I can"t seem to get the output to appear.

Here is the html:

```
<body>

<textarea id="text" rows="26" cols="80"></textarea>

<form>
<input type="button" id="analyse" value="Analyse Text">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

</body>
```

The JavaScript file has 6 functions. The first function returns an array that stores the number of characters for each word in the input textarea:

```
function getWordInfo() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    //the variable wordArray uses a regular expression to parse the input
    var wordArray = text.split("/\w\w+/g");
    var arrayLength = wordArray.length;
    var charArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var splitWord = wordArray[i].split("");
        var wordLength = splitWord.length;
        charArray.push(wordLength);
        }
    return charArray;
}
```

The second function is a simple object constructor that has a name property and a count property. The count property has a default value of 0.

```
function obCon(name,count) { //object constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    count = typeof count !== "undefined" ? count : 0;
}
```

The third function returns an array that stores word objects. Each object has a name property and a count property. The name property is the number of characters in a word. The count property counts how many times an object with a given name property appears.

```
function arCon() { //array constructor 
    var charNum = getWordInfo();
    var arrayLength = charNum.length;
    var obArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (typeof obArr.indexOf( newOb.name === charNum[i] ) != "undefined" ) { // checks if the object needed exists 
            obArr.indexOf( newOb.name === charNum[i] ).count = obArr.indexOf( newOb.name === charNum[i] ).count + 1;
    }else{
            var newOb = new obCon(charNum[i]);
            newOb.count = newOb.count + 1;
            obArr.push(newOb);
            }
        }
    return obArr;
}
```

The fourth function is a string formatter, meant format the objects from arCon into a single readable string, then store it in an array.

```
function formatter() {
    var strAr = arCon();
    var arrayLength = strAr.length;
    var formatStr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var str = "Number of characters: " + strAr[i].name + ", Number of words with this length: " + strAr[i].count;
        formatStr.push(str);
    }
    return formatStr;
}
```

The fifth function is called for an event handler, meant to handle the click of the analyse button. On click, it is meant to get the div tag, get the formatted array, then loop though each element in the array, where it creates a p element element, pulls the formatted string, sets the p element value to the formatted string, then appends the p element to the div tag.

```
function analyseButtonClick() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    var str = formatter();
    var arrayLength = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var par = document.createElement("p");
        var format = str[i];
        par.value = format;
        div.appendChild(par);
    }
}
```

The sixth function is an init function that handles the button click.

```
function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("analyse");
    button.onclick = analyseButtonClick;
}

window.onload = init;
```

I have run this though a validator, and it shows me that there are no syntax errors, so it must be a logic error. However, all the functions seem to do what they are supposed to do, so I am not sure where I went wrong.

edit1: ok, have replaced the third function with four new functions. a function that returns the highest number in the array returned by getWordInfo, a function that constructs objects with name properties from 2 up to that number, a function that update the count properties of the objects, and a function that removes unused objects. here they are:

```
function maxNum() {
    var array = getWordInfo();
    var num = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    return num;
}

function objArrCon() { //object array constructor 
    var num = maxNum();
    var array1 = [];
    for (var i = 2; i === num; i++) {
        var myObj = new objCon(i,0);
        array1.push(myObj);
    }
    return array1;
}

function objArrParse() { //updates the object with word info
    var array1 = getWordInfo();
    var array2 = objArrCon();
    var loopLength1 = array1.length;
    var loopLength2 = array2.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < loopLength1; i++) {
        for (var m = 0; m < loopLength2; m++) {
            if (array2[m].name === array1[i]) {
                array2[m].count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return array2;
}

function objArrTrun() { //removes unused objects
    var array1 = objArrParse();
    var loopLength = array1.length;
    for (var i = 0;i < loopLength; i++) {
        if (array1[i].count === 0) {
        array.splice(i, array1);
        }
    }
    return array1;
}
```

still does not work, but im getting there!

Comment: Have you tried putting in a break point in your analyseButtonClick function to see if your variable str actually had anything in it?

Comment: um, what would be the syntax for that? i have not worked with break points that much. do you mean like /br?

Comment: use the chrome developer tools. Start your app in chrome and then click F12. Navigate to Sources, select the file that has the analyseButtonClick and then click on the left hand side (on the line number) to put in a break point

Comment: cool, never done that before

Comment: alternatively, you can add a alert(str) in the analyseButtonClick to see what you have...

Comment: i used the chrome development tools and on this line: "if (typeof obArr.indexOf( newOb.name === charNum[i] ) != "undefined" )" it said: Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property "name" of undefined. what does that mean?

Comment: it means that one of the objects where you try and call the name property (i.e. newOb.name) is undefined, which means you have errors in your logic...

Comment: ya in your arCon method, you never say what newOb is

Comment: ok, going to work on reformulating the arCon method. thank you

Comment: my pleasure, let me know if you get into any more difficulties

Comment: how do i test whether an object exists in an array?

Comment: i meant, an object with a given name property?

Comment: put a break point where you want to check and then use the console. so for example if you want to see whats in newOb in the console just write newOb and click enter

Comment: i meant in pure syntax

Comment: if (object != undefined) { // code }

Comment: what i need to do is have the function check whether an object exists, if it does, pull the object and increment its count property. if it does not exists, then create the object with a new name property, and a count property of one.

Comment: oh, ok. but is that not what "if (typeof obArr.indexOf( newOb.name === charNum[i] ) != "undefined" )" does?

Comment: if (myObj != undefined) {
    myObj.count++;
} else {
   myObj = { name: "myName", count: 1 }
}

Comment: ok, but what i need to do is compare the name property of the object with the current element of the charNum array that i am looping though, to make sure i have the right one. sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: so something like"if (myObj.name === charNum[i] != undefined) {myObj.count++}

Comment: equality checks in javascript are done using "==="... is that helpful?

Comment: no, you want if (myObj.name === charNum[i]) { myObj.count++; }

Comment: maybe i should make a new function for comparisons? i need to do two things. i need to compare an object name property with the current element of the array i am looping though, and i need to check whether that object exists. what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I'm not deep into the logic of how your app should work. But it seems to me that you should first check whether the object exists, then check if the name matches. For example:

Comment: if (myObj != undefined && myObj != null) {
 if (myObj.name === otherName) {
  // do whatever } }

Comment: ok, i have "if (exists(compare(myObj.name, charNum[i]))) {do this;}" where exists and compare are functions that return booleans in an if/else structure, the first to see if it exists, and the second to compare the name property and the array element. i have tested it, still does not seem to work.

Comment: ya because you are first comparing and then checking existence, do it the other way around, check existence and then compare. if (exists(myObj)) { if (compare(myObj.name, charNum[i]) { do this; } }

Comment: ok, i going to make a function find the highest number in the array, then make a function to define all the objects with name properties up to and including that number. that way, i dont have to check wether it exists. how does that sound?

Comment: too was too meta for JavaScript anyway

Comment: try it out see if it works

Comment: thank you for your help, will be a while.

Comment: see edits, in the chrome developer tools, there are no number lines, and how do you get it to activate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this in jQuery because 1) it's not my homework assignment and 2) it would be good practice (for you) to translate it back into normal JavaScript. You'll need to rewrite the event handler, along with the two getters/setters (`$("text area").val()` and `$("tbody").append()`).

Your main problem is that you have made your solution too complicated! If all you want to do is display the number, `Y`, of words with length, `X`, then you should do the following:

1. Grab the value of the text area and store in `text`
2. Remove all non-alphanumeric characters.
3. Split the `text` string wherever one or more spaces is present and store it in `text`
4. Loop through the array and map each array element, based on its length, to `wordMap`
5. Loop through `wordMap` and append it to wherever in the DOM you want the results to be

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/yDh3X/3/)

**JavaScript**

```
$("#analyze").click(function () {
    var text = $("textarea").val().replace(/[^\d\w ]+/g," ").split(/[ ]+/);
    // this grabs the value of the text area, replaces all non-numerical
    // and non-alphabetical characters with "", and then splits it into an array
    // wherever one or more spaces is present.
    
    var wordMap = {};
    // makes an object that will be used as an associative array
    
    text.forEach(function (d) {
    // loops through the array
        
        // if there is no key called d.length in wordMap
        if (!wordMap[d.length])
            wordMap[d.length] = 1;  // set its count to one
        else
            wordMap[d.length]++;    //otherwise, increment it
    })
    
    // loop through all the properties of wordMap
    for (var x in wordMap) {
        $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>"
                          + wordMap[x] + "</td></tr");
    }
    console.log(wordMap);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea placeholder="type something..."></textarea>
<button id="analyze">Click to analyze</button>
<div id="results">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Length of Word</th>
            <th>Number of Occurrences</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```